# Clone private github repository using ansible with deploy key

Tags: git, github, ansible, ssh-keys

I am trying to deploy apps using Ansible playbook and builtin git module. But seems to Ansible didn't interpolate git repository url to the command.

Variables from inventory are present. Values are correct. And private key permissions are: .ssh dir - 0700, public keys - 644, private keys: 0600. User and group is ec2_user.

```
---
servers:
  hosts:
    "<ip_address>":
      ansible_user: "ec2-user"
      ansible_group: "ec2-user"
      ...
      web:
        git:
          public_key: "./.certs/github.web.id_rsa.pub"
          private_key: "./.certs/github.web.id_rsa"
          repo: "git@github.com:<organisation>/web-repo-name.git"
      ...
      data: 
        git:
          public_key: "./.certs/github.data.id_rsa.pub"
          private_key: "./.certs/github.data.id_rsa"
          repo: "git@github.com:<organisation>/data-repo-name.git"
      ...
```

Playbook

```
- name: Ensure .ssh directory exists.
        ansible.builtin.file:
          path: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/.ssh"
          state: directory
          mode: 0700
          owner: '{{ansible_user}}'
          group: '{{ansible_user}}'
        register: command_output
      - ansible.builtin.debug: 
          msg: "{{command_output}}"
      - name: Ensure GitHub private deploy key is present on the server.
        ansible.builtin.copy:
          content: "{{ item }}"
          dest: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/.ssh/{{ item | basename }}"
        with_items:
          - "{{ web.git.private_key }}"
          - "{{ web.git.public_key }}"
          - "{{ data.git.private_key }}"
          - "{{ data.git.public_key }}"
        register: command_output
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ command_output }}"
      - name: Ensure permissions for private keys.
        ansible.builtin.file:
          path: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/.ssh/{{ item | basename }}"
          state: file
          mode: 0600
          owner: '{{ansible_user}}'
          group: '{{ansible_user}}'
        with_items:
          - "{{ web.git.private_key }}"
          - "{{ data.git.private_key }}"
        register: command_output
      - ansible.builtin.debug: 
          msg: "{{command_output}}"
      - name: Ensure permissions for public keys.
        ansible.builtin.file:
          path: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/.ssh/{{ item | basename }}"
          state: file
          mode: 0644
          owner: '{{ansible_user}}'
          group: '{{ansible_user}}'
        with_items:
          - "{{ web.git.public_key }}"
          - "{{ data.git.public_key }}"
        register: command_output
      - ansible.builtin.debug: 
          msg: "{{command_output}}"
      - name: Ensure .ssh directory exists.
        ansible.builtin.file:
          path: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/.ssh"
          state: directory
          mode: 0700
          owner: '{{ansible_user}}'
          group: '{{ansible_user}}'
        register: command_output
      - ansible.builtin.debug: 
          msg: "{{command_output}}"
      - name: Ensure GitHub private deploy key is present on the server.
        ansible.builtin.copy:
          content: "{{ item }}"
          dest: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/.ssh/{{ item | basename }}"
        with_items:
          - "{{ web.git.private_key }}"
          - "{{ web.git.public_key }}"
          - "{{ data.git.private_key }}"
          - "{{ data.git.public_key }}"
        register: command_output
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ command_output }}"
      - name: Ensure permissions for private keys.
        ansible.builtin.file:
          path: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/.ssh/{{ item | basename }}"
          state: file
          mode: 0600
          owner: '{{ansible_user}}'
          group: '{{ansible_user}}'
        with_items:
          - "{{ web.git.private_key }}"
          - "{{ data.git.private_key }}"
        register: command_output
      - ansible.builtin.debug: 
          msg: "{{command_output}}"
      - name: Ensure permissions for public keys.
        ansible.builtin.file:
          path: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/.ssh/{{ item | basename }}"
          state: file
          mode: 0644
          owner: '{{ansible_user}}'
          group: '{{ansible_user}}'
        with_items:
          - "{{ web.git.public_key }}"
          - "{{ data.git.public_key }}"
        register: command_output
      - ansible.builtin.debug: 
          msg: "{{command_output}}"
...
- name: Clone repositories to workdirs
    hosts: servers
    remote_user: '{{ansible_user}}'
    tasks:
      - name: Clone a data github repository
        ansible.builtin.git:
          accept_hostkey: true
          key_file: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/.ssh/{{ data.git.private_key | basename }}"
          repo: "{{ data.git.repo }}"
          version: master
          dest: /opt/app/data
          clone: yes
          update: yes
        register: command_output
      - ansible.builtin.debug: 
          msg: "{{command_output}}"
      - name: Clone a web github repository
        ansible.builtin.git:
          accept_hostkey: true
          key_file: "/home/{{ansible_user}}/.ssh/{{ web.git.private_key | basename }}"
          repo: "{{ web.git.repo }}"
          version: master
          dest: /opt/app/web
          clone: yes
          update: yes
        register: command_output
      - ansible.builtin.debug: 
          msg: "{{command_output}}"
```

Receiving next error:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [18.170.237.197]

TASK [Clone a data github repository] **********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [18.170.237.197]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin '' /opt/app/data", "msg": "Cloning into '/opt/app/data'...\nLoad key \"/home/ec2-user/.ssh/github.data.codenv.top.id_rsa\":********@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Cloning into '/opt/app/data'...\nLoad key \"/home/ec2-user/.ssh/github.data.codenv.top.id_rsa\": error in libcrypto\r\ngit@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n", "stderr_lines": ["Cloning into '/opt/app/data'...", "Load key \"/home/ec2-user/.ssh/github.data.codenv.top.id_rsa\": error in libcrypto", "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).", "fatal: Could not read from remote repository.", "", "Please make sure you have the correct access rights", "and the repository exists."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found cause.
I provided `git-ssh` link without schema name and used semicolon instead of slash after repository host name:

Wrong:

`"git@github.com:organization/web.git"`

Correct:

`"git+ssh://git@github.com/organization/web.git"`